# Hide / Disable default menu in Chrome Custom Tab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I have implemented new **Chrome Custom Tab** in android, I am using the following code to open

```
    String url = "http://www.flipkart.com/";
    int color = Color.BLUE;
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(color);
    intentBuilder.setShowTitle(true); 
    CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(
            this, intentBuilder.build(), Uri.parse(url), new  WebviewFallback());
```

I need to secure my URL or not like to show my URL to User, But there is a option **Open in Chrome** in default menu, By using this link user can open my URL in browser,By how hide the default menu?

[image: my output]

Comment: Chrome Custom Tabs should be used when you want to open a 3rd party Url or a 1st party one that is also available on the Web. 

If you are opening content that is exclusive to the app and therefore want a hidden Url, you may want to use the WebView or consider using a native UI.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. How exactly are you running this? On a phone with 6.0 Developer Preview?

Comment: @Suleiman19 For this we need to update Google chrome in your device, No need of 6.0,refer this https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, it's not possible to hide the overflow menu or "Open in Chrome" menu item.

Comment: Are you sure? Twitter have customized the menu by removing the default icons row. This means that there is a way to play with the menu items, if it's not possible to hide the whole menu.

Comment: Is it still the same ?, i.e we cannot hide overflow menu and URL bar in custom chrome tab.

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods for hiding the menu option in Chrome custom tabs

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Custom Tab actually uses Chrome app in user's mobile.

start activity in Chrome app by link, If chrome not installed on the user's mobile, it will use a webView as the default.

In fact, Chrome Custom Tabs is designed to display a web page where the user is sure that the programmer of that software does not have a phishing, Like a bank payment.

Therefore, you must show the options in the toolbar to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This can be hide by using app link assistant.

complete guideline for how to create app link can be found here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

after successful generation and verification the above header can be hidden.

I have implemented this and result is like
[image]

Answer (score -6):

You must add hiding flag before. To disable your URL parameter but it can't hide your site name.

> intentBuilder.enableUrlBarHiding();

Comment: I am asking about hide the menu overflow option in custom chrome