# Disable Chrome Options Menu - Android

Tags: android, mobile

I am trying to do SSO using Chrome Tabs in my Android Application.

Whenever the chrome comes in it also has options menu of chrome - Is there a way to disable this options menu.

Attached is a screenshot[image: app]

Comment: Add the code you have used to show the SSO

Comment: Dups of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449554/hide-disable-default-menu-in-chrome-custom-tab/37044432

Comment: are you using webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, currently is not possibile: you can add items but not remove the button.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this you should use `phonegap` instead of use chrome browser as webview [read the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/)

basically it runs `chrome webview on android`, and `safari webview on IOS` but without all `chrome/safari options`.

Comment: `phonegap` is called `cordova` since ages, while it is extremely limiting, because it only supports one single callback - while Android SDK often would require more than just one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `WebView` instead of `CustomTabs` - then there is nothing to hide away, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there so in my opinion you should use simple Android `webview` if you don't want your user to access these options.

Just create a new activity/fragment that contains `webview` and open your website or any url within it.

This might help you from android [developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) docs.

Also try this [example](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-webview-example) that might be useful.