# Android Chrome CustomTabsIntent customize toolbar design

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

As I'm facing some issue with WebView, I am attempting to utilize Chrome Custom Tabs (CustomTabsIntent). However, I encounter difficulties in customizing its toolbar. Specifically, I aim to remove the share and menu icons from the CustomTabsIntent toolbar. Is there any way to achieve this? Below is my code.

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.7.0'

CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            .setShowTitle(true)
            .setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange_color))
            .build();

customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse("https://developer.android.com"));
```

I want to remove menu and share icons in below toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove Share icon in Chrome Custom Tabs, just add `.setShareState(CustomTabsIntent.SHARE_STATE_OFF)`.

So, your code will be like this.

```
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            .setShowTitle(true)
            .setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange_color))
            .setShareState(CustomTabsIntent.SHARE_STATE_OFF)
            .build();
```

While for removing the Menu icon, <del>it seems that it's not possible at the time of this writing.</del> it's achievable only if you own/manage the destination url.

You can remove the Menu icon using [**App Links Assistant**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing). More info about the App Links Assistant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67105486/15835391).